# How to insert/find gaps in a table of sqlite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

My table in sqlite has column 'name' which takes input like prefix+integervalue. for example p1, p2. and if there are 5 rows p1, p2, p5, p7, p10. I know the input prefix as 'p' and my next insert value must be p3 after that p4, after that p6,p8,.. like that. please help me for a query to find this gaps or any API support, I am using content_provider in android programming. Please help me my client needs this..

Comment: it's easier for people to help you if they have some relevant **piece of code** to work on - please show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extract the number from the name, and use that to search for the next number:

```
SELECT 'p' || (substr(Name, length('p') + 1) + 1)
FROM MyTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM MyTable AS T2
                  WHERE T2.Name = 'p' || (substr(MyTable.Name, length('p') + 1) + 1))
ORDER BY substr(Name, length('p') + 1) + 1
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you query whole your table? So you get back the values p1,p2,p5,p7 and p10. Put them as String in an arraylist and iterate over them. Look which values you don't have.

Another possibility is creating a list programmaticaly with p0 to pXXXX. Iterate over them and look then in your db which names you don't have. Create the new records, add them in a list and push them to the db.

Or you just get the max and min value and fill everything up between them and push it to the db(create or replace).

Hope that helps in finding your algorithm.